# Why is application.rb different between Rails 4.1 and 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

If I run

```
rails new _4.1.0.beta1_ rails4.1app --skip-test-unit
```

I find this code in config/application.rb

```
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

While if Create a Rails 4.0 app:

```
rails new _4.0.2_ rails4.0app --skip-test-unit
```

I get this in config/application.rb

```
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

Doesnt rails 4.0.2 include active_model and action_view? I think it's related to introduction of Action Pack, but it's really bugging me that I don't know why the files are different.

Answer (score 1):

What I did is just opened that file's template in rails repo. Here's a [link](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b5c5121f67c88a2be1c56e810f5c64013351ce79/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/application.rb). You can read through history, or just clone repo and use `gitk` tool to do it a bit faster. Here's what I found:

Template for Rails 4.0:

```
<% if include_all_railties? -%>
require 'rails/all'
<% else -%>
# Pick the frameworks you want:
<%= comment_if :skip_active_record %>require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
<%= comment_if :skip_sprockets %>require "sprockets/railtie"
<%= comment_if :skip_test_unit %>require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
<% end -%>
```

Template for Rails current Rails master:

```
<% if include_all_railties? -%>
require 'rails/all'
<% else -%>
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
<%= comment_if :skip_active_record %>require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
<%= comment_if :skip_action_view %>require "action_view/railtie"
<%= comment_if :skip_sprockets %>require "sprockets/railtie"
<%= comment_if :skip_test_unit %>require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
<% end -%>
```

There's not much difference here. I believe it has to do something with dependency structure inside of Rails itself. For example, now ActionController doesn't state ActionView as a required part of it, so it should be loaded separately.

Comment: Upgrading from 4.0 to 4.1. Should I include require "active_model/railtie" AND require "action_view/railtie"?

Comment: As I've seen from ActionController railtie code, 'action_view/railtie' will be required anyway. I assume, that goes for ActiveRecord and ActiveModel too.